# How to dynamically explain TS that the property of the object has specific type

Tags: typescript

The example of the code in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-pzl2s

The issue I experience the object has two types of properties. At some point of time the data is fetched from the database which contains only `DRI` child-property and depending on the parent property additional child-properties should be added.

The types for the parent properties and the whole object are defined as following:

```
type BalanceModelSectionType = {
  DRI: {
    AI: number;
    AMDR: {
      from: number;
      to: number;
      [index: string]: number;
    };
    EAR: number;
    RDA: number;
    UL: number;
    unit: string;
    [index: string]: string | number | object;
  };
  quantity: number;
  converted: {
    quantity: number;
    unit: string;
  };
  percentage: number;
};

type BalanceModelContainerSectionType = {
  DRI: {
    AI: number;
    AMDR: {
      from: number;
      to: number;
      [index: string]: number;
    };
    EAR: number;
    RDA: number;
    UL: number;
    SC: number;
    [index: string]: number | object;
  };
  percentage: number;
  accomplished: number;
};

type BalanceModelType = {
  alanine: BalanceModelSectionType;
  arginine: BalanceModelContainerSectionType;
  // ... many others
  [index: string]: BalanceModelSectionType | BalanceModelContainerSectionType;
};
```

At some point of type the following object is received, but it's still missing some properties which are added in the `forEach` but results in TS error that the properties are missing

```
const model: BalanceModelType = {
  alanine: {
    DRI: {
      AI: 0,
      AMDR: {
        from: 0,
        to: 0
      },
      EAR: 0,
      RDA: 0,
      UL: 0,
      unit: ``
    }
  },
  arginine: {
    DRI: {
      AI: 0,
      AMDR: {
        from: 0,
        to: 0
      },
      EAR: 0,
      RDA: 0,
      UL: 0,
      SC: 0
    }
  }
};

const defaultSectionValues = {
  quantity: 0,
  converted: {
    quantity: 0,
    unit: ``
  },
  percentage: 0
};
const progressSectionValues = {
  percentage: 0,
  accomplished: 0
};

Object.keys(model).forEach(sectionName => {
  const section = model[sectionName];

  /*
  How to dynamically explain TS that the property of the object has specific type? */
  if (sectionName === `alanine`) {
    model[sectionName] = { DRI: section.DRI, ...progressSectionValues }; // Property 'SC' is missing in type
  } else {
    model[sectionName] = { DRI: section.DRI, ...defaultSectionValues }; // Property 'unit' is missing in type
  }
});
```

I will appreciate a lot if you can suggest a more correct way to provide types for the object, or maybe a possibility to handle type in a conditional way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
interface BaseType {
  ...
}

interface ExtendedType extends BaseType {
  quantity: number;
  ...
}

function isBaseType(obj: any): obj is BaseType {
  return obj.quantity === undefined;
}

function isExtendedType(obj: any): obj is ExtendedType {
  return obj.quantity !== undefined;
}

const getObject = (): BaseType | isExtendedType => {
  // dynamically return the object that it's either BaseType or ExtendedType
}

const obj = getObject();
if (isBaseType(obj)) {
  // now object here is of type BaseType
}
if (isExtendedType(obj)) {
  // now object here is of type ExtendedType
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint Kousha type guard indeed helped to solve the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have the case that a field might be filled at a later time, it means that the field will be either undefined or holds a value. You can do this in Typescript by declaring the respective field as optional, as such:

```
interface SomeType {
   field?: string; // the field is either set to a string, or undefined
   field2: string | undefined; // alternative syntax for the same thing as above
}
```

So you will need to declare all the fields that are not always set as potentially undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
type BalanceModelSectionType = {
  DRI: {
    AI: number;
    AMDR: {
      from: number;
      to: number;
      [index: string]: number;
    };
    EAR: number;
    RDA: number;
    UL: number;
    unit: string;
    [index: string]: string | number | object;
  };
  quantity?: number;
  converted?: {
    quantity: number;
    unit: string;
  };
  percentage?: number;
};
```

Use question mark to nullable fields